# Strange behavior with lists in foreach

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a List that tracks "alive" objects in runtime. And when I apply some behavior in items from this list I've found something strange (at least to me), for example, let's say that I want to damage each enemy in current scene, so (Items is a List of custom class)

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
{
    var enemiesWithLife = enemiesInScene.Items.FindAll(enemy => enemy.life > 1);

    foreach (var enemy in enemiesWithLife)
        enemy.TakeDamage(1);
}
```

The above code works as expected BUT if I want to apply something to ALL enemies and try something as

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
{
    foreach (var enemy in enemiesInScene.Items)
        enemy.TakeDamage(1);
}
```

When I press "C" only 1 enemy "TakeDamage" and an error about list been modified during iterating

[image]

- EnemiesInScene is an ScriptableObject, so the enemies list exist only in assets

BUT if I try same code, but make an find before, as

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
{
    var allEnemies = enemiesInScene.Items.FindAll(enemy => true);

    foreach (var enemy in allEnemies)
        enemy.TakeDamage(1);
}
```

Things work as expected again ... WHY?

### Edit

Codes asked in comments:

```
public void TakeDamage(int damage)
{
    if (currentLife <= 0)
        return;

    currentLife -= damage;

    if (currentLife <= 0)
        Die();
    else
        TakeHit();
}
```

> EnemiesInScene is an RuntimeSet

```
public class RuntimeSet : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<RuntimeItem> Items = new List<RuntimeItem>();

    public void Add(RuntimeItem thing)
    {
        if (!Items.Contains(thing))
            Items.Add(thing);
    }

    public void Remove(RuntimeItem thing)
    {
        if (Items.Contains(thing))
            Items.Remove(thing);
    }
}
```

> Runtime item

```
public class RuntimeItem : LazyComponents
{
    public RuntimeSet runtimeSet;

    private void OnEnable()
        => runtimeSet.Add(this);

    private void OnDisable()
        => runtimeSet.Remove(this);
}
```

And LazyComponents is only a lazy approach wrapper that inherits from monobehaviour to get some components as rigidbody2d, etc...

Comment: What's the code in `TakeDamage`, and is `Items` just a simple `get`/`set` property, or does your getter have some code in it (something like `get { return this.items.Where(p => p.life > 0); }`?

Comment: Hi @BenRubin, TakeDamage just reduce enemy life and verify if it has died. As said above Items is not a property, it's a List of custom component

Comment: Something's probably going on in your `Items` property.  It would help if you posted the code for the `Items` property, and also your custom class.

Comment: @BenRubin, I've edited question

Comment: What happens inside of `Die`

Comment: private void Die() => animator.SetBool("isAlive", false);

Answer (score 0):

foreach uses an enumerator, and enumerators can't change the underlying collection, but can, however, change any objects referenced by an object in the collection see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in)

2 solutions: copy the collection in Array or List (less performance)

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
{
    foreach (var enemy in enemiesInScene.Items.ToArray())
        enemy.TakeDamage(1);
}
```

or use for loop which allows the modification in collection (more performance) i recommand

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < enemiesInScene.Items.Length; i++)
    enemiesInScene.Items[i].TakeDamage(1);
```

Comment: It's parcially right, ur first loop work just fine, but second create problems because Items will change during time, so it apply TakeDamage to new things inserted in list, but anyway, thanks for ur time ;P

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = list.Count - 1; i != -1; i--)
    list.RemoveAt(i); // replace with useful code that can modify this list
```

Comment: I don't understand ur answer friend, I think that u don't understand it right, the problem is not about remove things from the list

Comment: `Collection was modified` is an error that gets thrown when your code (down the callstack somewhere) modified that collection. For example: it's a common practice to write call chains like this: Damage() -> OnDead() -> OnDisable() { /*code that removes this instance from lists hence the error*/ }

Comment: Code sample above addresses cases like this by not using enumerators at all + counting indices from last to first (so elements with index>=`i` can be removed from the list without invalidating this loop).

Answer (score 0):

I think that I've found my error, enumerator runs asynchronous, so it'll change while other things happen, so

When I try it

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
{
    var allEnemies = enemiesInScene.Items.FindAll(enemy => true);

    foreach (var enemy in allEnemies)
        enemy.TakeDamage(1);
}
```

AllEnemies is already filled, so any change in enemiesInScene.Items don't affect allEnemies, this is why in other case we got errors